# Neptune Jupyter notebook is not showing graph tab

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, gremlin, amazon-neptune, graph-notebook

In the Neptune notebook, I add the vertex as follow:

```
%%gremlin 

g.addV('labelC').property(T.id, '153')
```

Then I do the `gremlin -p v,oute,inv` option to see a visual graph representation as below. Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/notebooks-visualization.html

```
%%gremlin -p v,oute,inv

g.V().hasLabel('labelC')
```

However, I don't see the graph tab in the output.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The rendering hints are designed to help the renderer know how to draw the graph when a `path` step is present. In general to get a nice rendering it is best to use a `path` step. In your example there will just be a set of vertices so the hint is actually stopping any rendering. In many cases the hints are no longer needed. There are a lot of examples in [this notebook](https://github.com/aws/graph-notebook/blob/main/src/graph_notebook/notebooks/02-Visualization/Air-Routes-Gremlin.ipynb). An example of a simple rendering might be:

```
%%gremlin
g.V('44').outE().inV().path().by(elementMap())
```

The hints are not needed here as the `elementMap` step gives the renderer all it needs in order to create a visual. Please checkout the notebook linked above and let me know if you have any additional questions. That notebook explains all of the possible hints and ways to adjust the visuals in detail.

[image]