# Visualizing Gremlin query results from AWS Neptune - is there a way?

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune, graph-notebook

im a bit new on AWS Neptune. Currently using gremlin to query data from it. My question is, is there a way to view the query results visually? I tried creating a Notebook (Jupyter) that connects to my Neptune cluster but it doesn't show the option to view the query results in a graph.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Please see the answer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69811505/neptune-jupyter-notebook-is-not-showing-graph-tab

Comment: Were you able to get the visualizations you needed? Did that other post help?